# Prevent bots from registering accounts to prevent sending costly sms

Tags: android, sms, bots

I am a little bit confused
I am working on an Android application, where the user has to create an account by entering his phone number.
We want to validate the phone number by sending a sms to the number with a unique hash, that must then be sent back to the server by the client to verify the number.
So far, straight forward...

But now we have some concerns about bots sending us registration requests with random phone numbers our server will then try to validate by sending them sms
As sending sms from the server costs money, that is an easy way to ruin us...

I hope we are missing something? Is there a way around this?
How do whatsapp/Snapchat prevent this?

EDIT: We do NOT want to use captchas to verify humans. Snapchat / Whatsapp do not use them either

Comment: You must have seen captcha codes when you try to book tickets or do banking. Those captcha are used for the same

Comment: Snapchat and Whatsapp don't use captchas... either there is now an easy way to cause them some damage, or there is a different approach, as we do not want to use captchas

Comment: They record the number of requests from the same IP. For example if they get 5 requests on same day from same IP, they block the user.

Comment: Better Idea is pass the extra parameter with the request such as Android Device ID, IMEI, Locale,the dimension of the handset etc.. to validate.

Comment: Honestly speaking, it depends on your budget, whatsapp and snapchat can easily afford 5 fake requests from a single IP, that too in a scale of million fake requests per hour. But if you want to verify the user in very first attempt, I suggest you to use captcha services.